# How to pass application user names to the database server for audit purposes?

Tags: mysql, audit

Writing an application that will require a user to login.

I would like to use a table to store my user information; however, the user's ID will not be available to me when I create audits for all my tables.

Conversely, adding the user to the database itself will give me what I need but it's going to be A LOT of users.

What is the best practice here?  I need to be able to create table audits with a column that holds the id of the user that changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to pass an application user name to MySQL to be recorded in an audit table.

You can use a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html#set-variable-user-variables), which is local to the session in which it is created. Your application code will set it to the name of the logged-in user once it is authenticated. Your audit code can then reference that variable and retrieve the user name.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6697d9eb33740036c0f2400185e4a680)

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend it instead of creating users, because your table and index size will grow.

But, some companies doing what you said. Adding a new column on their tables like `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy`.

After the data change, they search their audit table with the table which is holding user information.

Comment: Even a billion different users won't be a problem if the is a suitable `INDEX`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just mention that the growing data size.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the audit?  With Stored routines?  Consider using the `USER()` function.  But be careful about how you define the functions; it may give you `root@localhost` instead of the actual "user".

Comment: Thanks, but I believe you missed the context of the question